# Цикл, в котором будут меняться постоянно только 2 значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for, while

Мне нужен цикл, в котором я хочу поочерёдно менять значение элемента, 0 и 1

Чтобы примерно вот так проиходило и определённое кол-во раз, которое я сам могу выбрать:

```
a = 0
a = 1
a = 0
a = 1
a = 0
a = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться остатком от деления на два

```
for i in range(10):
    a = i % 2
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` предоставляет средства которые полезно знать:

```
#
#                         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...                         
#                         ----------------------
for i in itertools.islice(itertools.cycle((0, 1)), 10):
#        -----------------                       -----
#        выбрать десять первых значений из генератора cycle

    print(i)
```